# How to arrange a custom view with some basic views like buttons and textviews in a custom layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I had prepared a custom view now i want to place that view with some other basic views through a custom layout. I dont know much about custom layouts. How can I arrange these views programatically in custom layout and then how can I inflate that layout.
Thanks in advance